# Delta Tracing with Triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a Delta tracing for several tables based on triggers. Im using sql server 2012.
To simplify my questions, I would like to look only at the **after update** trigger.

So here is the trace table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[History](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_History_Id]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()),
    [ObjectId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_History_Timestamp]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [ChangingUser] [varchar](max) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_History_ChangingUser]  DEFAULT (suser_sname()),
    [Column] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [OldValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NewValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_History] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now I would create a Trigger on a Table, which I would like to trace:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[T1_TraceUpdate]
   on [dbo].[T1]
   AFTER update
AS 
BEGIN
set nocount on;
-- pseudo insert!
insert into History select * from inserted;
END
```

Except for the layout not matching the History Table, I have issues determinating the values, which have been changed and whose untouched.
Is there a way to do it in a smarter way than just use dozends of *if(updated(col_name))*?
Also I have to keep in mind, that there might be multiple rows affected.
Is there a better and more resuable solution (possibly even without cursors?)...

*Edit #1: Sample Data for T1 and History*

T1 Design:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T1](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_T1_Id]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()),
    [Title] [text] NULL,
    [Amount] [int] NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](18, 7) NULL,
    [Version] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_T1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample Data could be like this:

```
1d118497-bf69-e611-9e7d-40a8f04d1095    Abc            3    37,2500000  
9cf095a8-bf69-e611-9e7d-40a8f04d1095    NULL           1    27,3000000  
cc38386d-fe69-e611-9e7d-40a8f04d1095    Storm Catcher  10   NULL
```

Lets fire a silly update:

```
update T1 set price = isnull(Price,100)*0.7 where Amount > 2
```

History should now look like this:

```
4848D80B-4E73-E611-BD43-40A8F04D1095    1D118497-BF69-E611-9E7D-40A8F04D1095    2016-09-05 11:49:33.473 sa  Price   37,2500000  26.0750000
E80EAB18-4E73-E611-BD43-40A8F04D1095    CC38386D-FE69-E611-9E7D-40A8F04D1095    2016-09-05 11:49:33.473 sa  Price   NULL        70
```

Comment: Firstly, don't ever write and insert/select combo without specifying columns   - hopefully that was just for your example. Secondly, why not just use `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms186329.aspx. You didn't mention how you wanted to store this info

Comment: ofc its just an example. I think the layout of my History table shows how I would like to store it. Obtailing user and time is obvious. From what I see in columns_updated(), I will have to create and execute dynamic querries, right?

Comment: My apologies I didn't read your post properly and missed your table. You would possibly need dynamic SQL to load into that table anyway because you need to identify the column and load it in. So decide whether you want dynamic SQL, hard coded SQL or a lower level replication system like database mirroring. Note with hard coded SQL you could actually autogenerate it dynamically. Write a proc that inspects tables and spits out a string that is the correct create trigger statement... like code autogeneration.

Comment: I prefer dynamic sql over code generation. Is it possible to also check for 'false' updates? Like update t1 set c1=c1 - those should not be traced...

Comment: I'm just going by the doco - I'm no expert on this - and it doesn't say whether those types of updates are included or not.

Comment: Could you please show some sample of data inserted in `T1` and what should be inserted in `history` and then if update this row in `T1` what should be changed in `history`

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Since SQL 2008, we've had Change Data Capture. Also, with SQL 2016, we got Temporal Tables.

Comment: I'm using sql 2012 and I just added some sample Data

Comment: Under no circumstances should you ever consider putting a cursor in a trigger.

Comment: @BenThul CDC is a good call, SQL also has change tracking which is lighter weight than CDC

Comment: have you tried with the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggers have [`inserted` and `deleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms191300.aspx) tables, which can be used to

> Find the difference between the state of a table before and after a
>   data modification and take actions based on that difference.
>
> An update transaction is similar to a delete operation followed by an
>   insert operation; the old rows are copied to the deleted table first,
>   and then the new rows are copied to the trigger table and to the
>   inserted table.

Unpivot these tables to have one row per column, compare them and insert into the `History` table only rows where old and new values differ.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[T1_TraceUpdate]
    on [dbo].[T1]
    AFTER update
AS 
BEGIN
    set nocount on;

    WITH
    CTE_Inserted
    AS
    (
        SELECT ID, ColumnName, ColumnValue
        FROM
            inserted
            CROSS APPLY
            (VALUES
                ('Title', Title),
                ('Amount', CAST(Amount AS nvarchar(max))),
                ('Price', CAST(Price AS nvarchar(max)))
            ) AS V(ColumnName, ColumnValue)
    )
    ,CTE_Deleted
    AS
    (
        SELECT ID, ColumnName, ColumnValue
        FROM
            deleted
            CROSS APPLY
            (VALUES
                ('Title', Title),
                ('Amount', CAST(Amount AS nvarchar(max))),
                ('Price', CAST(Price AS nvarchar(max)))
            ) AS V(ColumnName, ColumnValue)
    )
    INSERT INTO dbo.History([ObjectId], [Column], [OldValue], [NewValue])
    SELECT
        CTE_Inserted.Id AS [ObjectId]
        ,CTE_Inserted.ColumnName
        ,CTE_Deleted.ColumnValue AS [OldValue]
        ,CTE_Inserted.ColumnValue AS [NewValue]
    FROM
        CTE_Inserted
        INNER JOIN CTE_Deleted
            ON  CTE_Deleted.Id = CTE_Inserted.Id
            AND CTE_Deleted.ColumnName = CTE_Inserted.ColumnName
    WHERE
        ISNULL(CTE_Inserted.ColumnValue, N'') <> ISNULL(CTE_Deleted.ColumnValue, N'')
        OR (CTE_Inserted.ColumnValue IS NULL AND CTE_Deleted.ColumnValue IS NOT NULL) 
        OR (CTE_Inserted.ColumnValue IS NOT NULL AND CTE_Deleted.ColumnValue IS NULL) 
    ;

END
```

You'll have to use `nvarchar(max)` type instead of `text` in your `T1` table. And you'll have to convert/cast all values to `nvarchar(max)` (or have several columns in the `History` table for different types).

Comment: this would work, but I am looking for a more general solution where I do not need to specifiy every column in every trigger for every single table. I'd like to have a more dynamic and resuable solution. Still +1 for cross apply.

Comment: @Jaster, relational databases are designed to have stable schema, where columns are known in advance and don't change often. A quick search for "sp_executesql in trigger" tells that you can't run dynamic SQL in trigger that references `inserted` or `deleted` tables. Dynamic SQL is executed in a different separate context. People suggest to copy the `inserted` table to some temp table and reference that temp table in dynamic SQL. I'm not sure it will work and you still have to define the columns for temp table somehow. I'd have a close look at `Change Data Capture` feature.

Comment: looks like sql genearator is required... however why are you casting the id to nvarchar? (that column does not require to be traced)

Comment: @Jaster, you are right, it doesn't make much sense to include `ID` column, because it should not change. At the same time I didn't include `Version` column because it always changes and its actual values usually don't have useful (historical) meaning. I hope that the overall outline of the query makes it clear how to add more columns as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Jaster, Finally i got a solution for your query.

Its a dynamic script ,where you can mention the name of required tables. The script will manage the data change on the mentioned tables table across all columns (except columns with datatype text,ntext and image) by creating dynamic triggers which will get fired on `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` actions on these tables. You can change the actions as per your requirement.I also included `TableName` and `ModifiedDate` in your **HISTORY** table for an easy look up.

So here are the steps to your solution.

Creating sample test environment using the provided Information

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME= 'History')
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[History](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_History_Id]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()),
    [Tablename] VARCHAR(150),
    [ObjectId] VARCHAR(1500) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_History_Timestamp]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [ChangingUser] [varchar](max) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_History_ChangingUser]  DEFAULT (suser_sname()),
    [Column] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [OldValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NewValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
       [ModifiedDate] Datetime NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_History] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME= 'T1')

BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T1](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_T1_Id]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()),
    [Title] text NULL,
    [Amount] [int] NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](18, 7) NULL,
    [Version] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_T1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] 

INSERT INTO [T1] ([Title],[Amount],[Price],[Version]) VALUES ('Abc',3,372500000 ,'2016-09-01 11:49:33.473'),
                                         (NULL,1,273000000  ,'2016-09-02 11:49:33.473'),
                                         ('Storm Catcher',10,NULL,'2016-09-01 11:49:33.473')
END
```

In the below temporary table ,you have to insert the table names for which wanted to track the data changes.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FiltedTableList') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #FiltedTableList
GO

CREATE TABLE #FiltedTableList
( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  TableName VARCHAR(150))
INSERT INTO #FiltedTableList (TableName)
SELECT 'T1' --here we have only one table to track the changes
```

Here comes the final step. execute the below dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname,@Counter INT,@Dynamsql varchar(MAX) 
SELECT @Counter=MAX(ID) FROM #FiltedTableList

SET NOCOUNT ON

WHILE (@Counter !=0)

BEGIN

       SELECT @TableName= TableName
       FROM #FiltedTableList
       WHERE ID=@Counter

        DECLARE  @ColumnFilter VARCHAR (MAX)

        SELECT  @ColumnFilter=Stuff((   Select ', ' + C.COLUMN_NAME 
        From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C  Where  C.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
               AND c.DATA_TYPE NOT IN ('text','ntext','image')
                Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION   For Xml Path('')  ), 1, 2, '')


        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##MagInserted') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE ##MagInserted

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##MagDeleted') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE ##MagDeleted


EXEC('IF OBJECT_ID (''' + @TableName+ '_LogTracker'', ''TR'') IS NOT NULL DROP TRIGGER ' + @TableName+ '_LogTracker')
SELECT @Dynamsql =
 'CREATE TRIGGER ' + @TableName+ '_LogTracker ON ' + @TableName+ ' FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
  AS
  DECLARE   @column int , @maxColumn int , @char int,@columnname varchar(128) , @TableName varchar(128) , @KeyColumn varchar(1000) , @Dynamsql varchar(2000) ,@dataquery VARCHAR(MAX), 
            @ModifiedDate varchar(21), @UserName varchar(128) , @key int , @Type char(1) , @PKFieldSelect varchar(1000),@PKValueSelect varchar(1000)
  SELECT @TableName = ''' + @TableName+ ''';
  SELECT @UserName = system_user , @ModifiedDate = convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112) + '' '' + convert(varchar(12), getdate(), 114);
  SELECT '+ @ColumnFilter+' INTO ##MagInserted FROM inserted;SELECT '+ @ColumnFilter+' INTO ##MagDeleted FROM deleted;
   SELECT @KeyColumn = COALESCE(@KeyColumn + '' and'', '' on'') + '' i.'' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '' = d.'' + c.COLUMN_NAME
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS kc JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c ON c.TABLE_NAME = kc.TABLE_NAME and c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
  WHERE kc.TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = ''PRIMARY KEY''
  SELECT @PKFieldSelect = COALESCE(@PKFieldSelect+''+'','''') + '''''''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''''''''
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS kc JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c ON c.TABLE_NAME = kc.TABLE_NAME and c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
  WHERE kc.TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = ''PRIMARY KEY''
  SELECT @PKValueSelect = coalesce(@PKValueSelect+''+'','''') + ''convert(varchar(100), coalesce(i.'' + COLUMN_NAME + '',d.'' + COLUMN_NAME + ''))''
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS kc JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c ON c.TABLE_NAME = kc.TABLE_NAME  and c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
  WHERE  kc.TABLE_NAME = @TableName  AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = ''PRIMARY KEY''  
  SELECT @column = 0 , @maxColumn = max(ORDINAL_POSITION) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
              WHILE @column < @maxColumn
              BEGIN
                     SELECT @column = min(ORDINAL_POSITION) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND ORDINAL_POSITION > @column
                     SELECT @key = (@column - 1 )% 8 + 1; SELECT @key = power(2,@key - 1);SELECT @char = ((@column - 1) / 8) + 1
                   IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @key > 0 OR @Type IN (''I'',''D'')
                           BEGIN
                           SELECT @columnname = COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName and ORDINAL_POSITION = @column
                           SELECT @Dynamsql = ''insert History (TableName,[ObjectId], [Column], OldValue, NewValue, ModifiedDate, ChangingUser)''
                           SELECT @Dynamsql = @Dynamsql + '' select '''''' + @TableName + '''''''' 
                           SELECT @Dynamsql = @Dynamsql +  '','' + @PKValueSelect
                           SELECT @Dynamsql = @Dynamsql + '','''''' + @columnname + ''''''''
                           SELECT @Dynamsql = @Dynamsql + '',convert(varchar(1000),d.'' + @columnname + '')''
                           SELECT @Dynamsql = @Dynamsql + '',convert(varchar(1000),i.'' + @columnname + '')''
                           SELECT @Dynamsql = @Dynamsql + '','''''' + @ModifiedDate + ''''''''
                           SELECT @Dynamsql = @Dynamsql + '','''''' + @UserName + ''''''''
                           SELECT @Dynamsql = @Dynamsql + '' from ##MagInserted i full outer join ##MagDeleted d''
                           SELECT @Dynamsql = @Dynamsql + @KeyColumn
                           SELECT @Dynamsql = @Dynamsql + '' where i.'' + @columnname + '' <> d.'' + @columnname
                           SELECT @Dynamsql = @Dynamsql + '' or (i.'' + @columnname + '' is null and  d.'' + @columnname + '' is not null)''
                           SELECT @Dynamsql = @Dynamsql + '' or (i.'' + @columnname + '' is not null and  d.'' + @columnname + '' is null)''
                           EXEC (@Dynamsql)
                           END    END   '
SELECT @Dynamsql
EXEC(@Dynamsql)

SET @Counter=@Counter-1

END
```

So here is the test case and output :

[image]

Comment: Smart solution, but I am not looking for a dynamic script to generate the triggers. My questsion was about dynamic sql as part of the trigger - which appears not to be an option.

Answer (score 2):

Join inserted, selected and check columns. Note NULL safe non-equality comparison,  setting not-NULL value to NULL and vise versa is counted as changed data.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[T1_TraceUpdate]
    on [dbo].[T1]
    AFTER update
AS 
BEGIN
    set nocount on;
    -- Changing Id breaks the logic of the trigger
    IF UPDATE(ID) 
    BEGIN 
        RAISERROR ('ID cannot change.', 16, 1);
        --
    END     
    INSERT INTO dbo.History(ObjectId, [Column], OldValue, NewValue)
    SELECT inserted.ID, ColumnName, OldValue, NewValue
    FROM inserted 
    INNER JOIN Deleted ON  Deleted.Id = Inserted.Id
    CROSS APPLY
       (SELECT ColumnName='Title', OldValue=deleted.Title, NewValue=inserted.Title 
          WHERE isnull(nullif(inserted.Title,deleted.Title), nullif(deleted.Title,inserted.Title)) IS NOT NULL 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Amount', CAST(deleted.Amount AS nvarchar(max)), CAST(inserted.Amount AS nvarchar(max))
          WHERE isnull(nullif(inserted.Amount,deleted.Amount), nullif(deleted.Amount,inserted.Amount)) IS NOT NULL  
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Price', CAST(deleted.Price AS nvarchar(max)), CAST(inserted.Price AS nvarchar(max))
          WHERE isnull(nullif(inserted.Price, deleted.Price), nullif(deleted.Price,inserted.Price)) IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        -- you may want to skip version (`timestamp` type) as it's always updated by server
        SELECT 'Version', CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(VARBINARY,deleted.Version),1), CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(VARBINARY,inserted.Version),1)
          WHERE isnull(nullif(inserted.Version, deleted.Version), nullif(deleted.Version,inserted.Version)) IS NOT NULL
     ) t;
END;
```

Comment: I'm looking for a more generic solution, applieable to multiple tables without the need of specifying every single column. +1 for correct null checks and understanding the Version column.

Comment: I can only think about SQLCLR trigger which can build and exec SQL like that on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you our proprietary solution, but I can suggest an approach. What we do is we have a script that looks up the columns for a specified table in the systems tables and then generates the trigger code using dynamic SQl with a loop to grab all the columns one at a time.

We run this script every time a change to the structure of the table is made or a new table we want to audit is created.  So the actual trigger looks somewhat similar to the other solutions posted, but it is created through a script that uses dynamic SQL to go through all the columns and add them to the script to create the trigger.

This is faster and less open to mistakes and missing something than generating each trigger by hand.  This approach has been working flawlessly for over 15 years on our legacy database. To keep things easier to understand, we have one trigger for inserts, one for deletes and one for updates for each table.

Comment: I guess this is where I am already heading, based on vladimirs answer... Just need some more insight on the required conversions.

Comment: @Jaster, it is tempting to put this dynamic SQL code that generates the code of the DML trigger in the [DDL Trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms175941.aspx). Thus you'll guarantee that your main DML trigger that logs changes to the data is always in sync with the table schema. But, I don't know if it is possible to `ALTER` or `DROP/CREATE` a DML trigger within a DDL trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also CDC (Change Data Capture)

1. Enable DB for CDC
2. Enable table/columns for CDC
3. Read CDC tables to read the changes (each actual change has old and new row, + $updatemask where you can find updated columns. It automatically excludes fake updates)

All that stuff can be done dynamically for each table.

The triggers slow down the OLTP system. Transaction is not committed till the trigger finishes. CDC works after transaction is committed and when you want - CDC scanner reads directly transactional log, like in transactional replication. The advantage of CDC is that you read CDC tables, not the base tables. You can delay the process and read / populate history tables during quiet times, e.g. on weekends or overnight.

Comment: Is it possible to modifiy the data written during cdc process. e.g. change the user/time?

Comment: do you mean to change cdc table? Yes, you can change the CDC data. CDC scanner reads transactional log and populate CDC tables. Then you can do any DML commands against those tables, but it's not needed as you read from CDC tables and populate your history tables